Parse file to identify CodePage/Characterset
I want to parse text files with Perl to get the following information:

LineBreak + Codepage/Characterset

no "guess" (like linux "file"-command), but really parse full file.
Encode::Guess is not helping as it is not distinguishing what I need.
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w
    
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Encode::Guess;
    Encode::Guess->add_suspects(qw/latin1/);
    
    my $data;
    my $decoder;
    
    foreach my $filename (@ARGV) {
        open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "cannot open file $filename";
        {
            local $/;
            $data = <$fh>;
        }
        close($fh);
        $decoder = Encode::Guess->guess($data);
        ref($decoder) ? print "$filename: " . $decoder->name . $/ : print "$filename: $decoder $/" ;
    }

output:
testfile_LF_ANSI.txt: iso-8859-1
testfile_LF_ASCII.txt: ascii
testfile_LF_UTF-16BE_BOM.txt: UTF-16
testfile_LF_UTF-16LE_BOM.txt: UTF-16
testfile_LF_UTF-8.txt: Encodings too ambiguous: utf8 or iso-8859-1
testfile_LF_UTF-8_BOM.txt: utf8
testfile_LF_UTF-8_only_ISO8859-1.txt: Encodings too ambiguous: iso-8859-1 or utf8
testfile_LF_UTF-8_only_ISO8859-2.txt: Encodings too ambiguous: iso-8859-1 or utf8
testfile_LF_UTF-8_only_ISO8859-5.txt: Encodings too ambiguous: iso-8859-1 or utf8

I deal with the following encodings

ASCII
IS0-8859-1 (Latin1)
IS0-8859-2 (Latin2)
IS0-8859-5 (Cyrilic)
UTF-8

and following characters (I need somehow to define these in perl)

MyLatin1 (subset of Latin1-characters I am using)
MyLatin2 (subset of Latin2-characters I am using)
MyCyrillic (subset of Cyrillic-characters I am using)

following tests required:

linebreak
(Mac "CR" skipped on purpose as not needed - but for sure can be added)

    1. no linebreak
    2. only "LF"
    3. only "CR LF"
    4. mixture of "LF" + "CR LF"


Codepage/Characterset

    1. \xEF\xBB\xBF -> UTF8 BOM
    2. \xFF\xFE -> UTF-16LE BOM
    3. \xFE\xFF -> UTF-16BE BOM
    4. only ASCII characters -> ASCII
    5. UTF-8 validation (as not all sequences of bytes are valid UTF-8) -> valid UTF-8
    6. UTF-8 holding only ISO-8859-1 characters -> UTF-8 + subset of Latin1-characters
    7. UTF-8 holding only ISO-8859-2 characters -> UTF-8 + subset of Latin2-characters
    8. UTF-8 holding only ISO-8859-5 characters -> UTF-8 + subset of Cyrillic-characters
    9. UTF-8 holding only ISO-8859-1/ISO-8859-2/ISO-8859-5 characters -> UTF-8 + mixture of (ISO-8859-1 to ISO-8859-5
    10. ANSI guess against MyLatin1 (only if not (4 & 5)) -> most probably ISO-8859-1 (as only MyLatin1-Bytes used)
    11. ANSI guess against MyLatin2 (only if not (4 & 5)) -> most probably ISO-8859-2 (as only MyLatin2-Bytes used)
    12. ANSI guess against MyCyrillic (only if not (4 & 5)) -> most probably ISO-8859-5 (as only MyLatin5-Bytes used)
    13. if not (4 & 5 & 10 & 11 & 12) -> ANSI with bytes outside MyLatin1, MyLatin2 and MyCyrillic 

Question
linebreak (1-4) and Codepage/Characterset (1-4) I know how to do.
But any idea, how I can

define my custom characters (ANSI-bytes) for

MyLatin1
MyLatin2
MyCyrillic


do the Codepage/Characterset checks 5-12?


Can you upload the test files somewhere? Then we can try to experiment with them. Also state what should be the expected output for those files

Macs use LF. Only very old MacOS used CR.

There are two separate things we are trying to determine, the encoding of the encoded text (1 to 5, and 10 to 13), and which charset can represent the string (6 to 9).
Detecting the encoding
4. Detecting if the encoding is ASCII.
This one is easy. Of the encodings in question, any sequence of bytes that's valid ASCII will be ASCII. So all we need to do with check if it's valid ASCII.
We can do so using a regex match.
my $is_ascii = $bytes =~ /^[\x00-\x7F]*\z/;

We can do so by attempting to decoded it:
use Encode qw( decode );

sub test_decoding {
   my $encoding = shift;
   my $bytes    = shift;

   return !!eval {
      decode( $encoding, $bytes, Encode::FB_CROAK|Encode::LEAVE_SRC );
      1
   };
}

my $is_ascii = test_decoding( "ASCII", $bytes );

5. Detecting if the encoding is UTF-8
This one is easy. Valid UTF-8 is very unlikely to be iso-8859-1. I presume it's equally unlikely to be iso-8859-2 or iso-8859-5. So all we need to do is check if it's valid UTF-8.
We can do so using a regex match.
my $is_utf8 = $bytes =~ /
   ^
   (?: [\x00-\x7F]                                       # U+000000 .. U+00007F
   |   [\xC2-\xDF] [\x80-\xBF]                           # U+000080 .. U+0007FF
   |   \xE0        [\xA0-\xBF] [\x80-\xBF]               # U+000800 .. U+000FFF
   |   [\xE1-\xEC] [\x80-\xBF] [\x80-\xBF]               # U+001000 .. U+00CFFF
   |   \xED        [\x80-\x9F] [\x80-\xBF]               # U+00D000 .. U+00D7FF
   |   [\xEE-\xEF] [\x80-\xBF] [\x80-\xBF]               # U+00E000 .. U+00FFFF
   |   \xF0        [\x90-\xBF] [\x80-\xBF] [\x80-\xBF]   # U+010000 .. U+03FFFF
   |   [\xF1-\xF3] [\x80-\xBF] [\x80-\xBF] [\x80-\xBF]   # U+040000 .. U+0FFFFF
   |   \xF4        [\x80-\x8F] [\x80-\xBF] [\x80-\xBF]   # U+100000 .. U+10FFFF
   )*
   \z
/x;

We can do so by attempting to decoded it:
my $is_utf8 = test_decoding( "UTF-8", $bytes );

10 to 12. Detecting which single-byte encoding
This one is hard. Very hard. It will require a lot of work to come up with and implement appropriate heuristics.
For example, we could use a dictionary of word or word parts that can only be encoded using one of these encodings and search for the encoded form of these words ("signatures") in the encoded text.
13. Detecting that it's not any of the above
This is virtually impossible. And we assumed it would never be the case as early as 4.
Detecting the character set of decoded text
Two approaches.
We could check if the decoded text is limited to each of the character sets using using regex patterns.
my $a_8859_1_char = qr/[\x00-\xFF]/;
my $a_8859_2_char = qr/[\x00-\xA0\xA4\xA7\xA8\xAD\xB0\xB4\xB8\xC1\xC2\xC4\xC7\xC9\xCB\xCD\xCE\xD3\xD4\xD6\xD7\xDA\xDC\xDD\xDF\xE1\xE2\xE4\xE7\xE9\xEB\xED\xEE\xF3\xF4\xF6\xF7\xFA\xFC\xFD\x{102}-\x{107}\x{10C}-\x{111}\x{118}-\x{11B}\x{139}\x{13D}\x{13E}\x{141}-\x{144}\x{147}\x{148}\x{150}\x{151}\x{154}\x{155}\x{158}-\x{15B}\x{15E}-\x{165}\x{16E}-\x{171}\x{179}-\x{17E}\x{2C7}\x{2D8}\x{2D9}\x{2DB}\x{2DD}\x{103A}]/;
my $a_8859_3_char = qr/[\x00-\xA0\xA7\xAD\x{401}-\x{40C}\x{40E}\x{40F}\x{410}-\x{429}\x{42A}-\x{44F}\x{451}-\x{45C}\x{45E}\x{45F}\x{2116}]/;

my $is_8859_1_compat = $decoded_text =~ /^$a_8859_1_char*\z/;
my $is_8859_2_compat = $decoded_text =~ /^$a_8859_2_char*\z/;
my $is_8859_5_compat = $decoded_text =~ /^$a_8859_5_char*\z/;

Or we could try encoding the decoded text using the encodings.
use Encode qw( encode );

sub test_encoding {
   my $encoding     = shift;
   my $decoded_text = shift;

   return !!eval {
      encode( $encoding, $decoded_text, Encode::FB_CROAK|Encode::LEAVE_SRC );
      1
   };
}


my $is_8859_1_compat = test_encoding( "iso-8859-1", $decoded_text );
my $is_8859_2_compat = test_encoding( "iso-8859-2", $decoded_text );
my $is_8859_5_compat = test_encoding( "iso-8859-5", $decoded_text );

Either way, keep in mind that more than one of these flags can be true at the same time. For example, the following string isn't valid ASCII, but is it valid UTF-8.
41 42 43 C2 A0 44 45 46

Once decoded, it becomes the following string, which only uses characters from -1, only uses characters from -2, and only uses characters from -5.
41 42 43 A0 44 45 46

It's unclear what's wanted for 9.
If we want to determine if the text can be encoded using any of -1, -2 and -5, we can use the following:
my $is_8859_any_compat =
   (  $is_8859_1_compat
   || $is_8859_2_compat
   || $is_8859_5_compat
   );

But there are two other ways to read the request, though I can't fathom a use for either.
To determine if the text contains only character from the union of the three character sets, we can use the following:
my $is_8859_mixture = $decoded_text =~ /^(?:$a_8859_1_char|$a_8859_2_char|$a_8859_5_char)*\z/;

To determine if the text contains only character from the union of the three character sets, but not from any one individual set, we can use the following:
my $is_strictly_8859_mixture = 
   (  $is_8859_mixture 
   && !$is_8859_1_compat
   && !$is_8859_2_compat
   && !$is_8859_5_compat
   );

